# Jquery Ajax não exibe object no método PUT, usando .net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, .net, mvc

eu possuo o object `var obj = { nome: "Felipe", idade: 23 }`

Criei uma chamada ajax pelo jquery assim:

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'ConfigCode/UpdateOptionsStatus', // route controller na web
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
});
```

No Controller da web `ConfigCode` eu criei o metodo `UpdateOptionsStatus`:

```cs
        [HttpPut]
        public ActionResult UpdateOptionsStatus(object objectToSend)
        {
            RestHelper.Put(objectToSend, $"ConfigCode/Update");

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

O que no `objectToSend` de fato carrega um `{object}`

No controller `ConfigCode` da API, eu criei o método `Update` para recebe-la:

```cs
        [HttpPut, IgnorePermission]
        public HttpResponseMessage Update(object optionsToUpdate)
        {
            (...)

            if (result == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Porém não chega o `{Object}` enviado. Chega uma marcação vazia `{{}}` em `optionsToUpdate`

### Onde está o erro?

Comment: por que no lugar de receber um `object`, não cria uma classe model e recebe ela como parâmetro? são só 2 properties bem simples

Comment: sim funcionou. fiz um Update(List<ViewModelCriada> optionsToUpdate) e mudei o objeto para um array de objetos com as properties da ViewModel.

Comment: boa Luke, o serializer/deserializer funciona melhor com tipos definidos, object, dynamic e afins são complicados para isso :)